# Mac OS counterpart to Sysinternals and Powertoys

Tags: macos

As a developer coming from a Windows background, I'd always find the different [Powertoys](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) and [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) apps as invaluable tools in aiding programming. Is there something similar for a developer to watch for in the Mac world?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A lot of those types of tools are included with the Mac OS, and some are available separately from Apple.

There's no Mac equivalent of the registry - everything goes in the file system somewhere - and you can use fs_usage to watch that.  In a terminal:

`sudo fs_usage`

Check out [Instruments](http://www.apple.com/macosx/developertools/instruments.html), part of the Apple developer tools distribution.

Comment: Not entirely true -- OSX inherits the netinfo database from NextStep which is similar in some ways to the registry.

Comment: Instruments looks awesome, how do I run it?

Comment: Thanks for 'fs_usage'. I had read Amit Singh OSX internals, and couldn't remember what it was.

Comment: Instruments can be run from within Xcode: in the Run menu goto the Start  with Performance Tool, and anything under Instruments Templates will run Instruments. It can also be found in /Developer/Applications.

Comment: Netinfo has been gone since OS X 10.5.  Since 2007.  It was totally replaced by Directory Services.  I'm not sure I'd compare it to the registry anyway though. It helped manage users, groups and network accounts, but was limited to that scope and wasn't a proprietary DB with proprietary types like the registry.  It was also much, much smaller in scope compared to the registry.  (I'm commenting on Adam's comment)

Comment: there is also `sc_usage` for syscalls.

Answer (score 4):

[Top 10 DTrace scripts for Mac OS X](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/) is an article that describes ten really useful tools that are Mac equivalents of some of the Sysinternals tools such as ProcessMon, FileMon, etc.

The post's author created some of the scripts when he made the [DTraceToolkit](http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html#DTraceToolkit), which he says Apple then customized and enhanced for inclusion by default in Mac OS X.

Some script names look like they end with the word "noop," which might be a bit confusing--it's actually "snoop." As in spying on system activity.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X comes with a lot of unix tools like sar, top, etc. What metrics are you looking for specifically?

Comment: Some of the Powertoys I use are Open Command Window Here and Image Resizer, and DiskMon and Process Explorer + AutoRuns for Sysinternals.

Answer (score 0):

Not as such. Some of the Powertoys implement features that are built-in to the OS, some are available as various utility programs.

As for Sysinternals, there are quite a lot of them. If you want specifics I'd need a better idea of what you use, but you could probably duplicate 90% of the functionality just from a terminal window. Learning how to use bash and the normal Unix utilities would be a very good skill to have.

Answer (score 0):

http://newosxbook.com/index.php?page=downloads provide almost exact counterparts, albeit in CLI mode - with the upside that they also work on (jailbroken) iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [objective-see](https://objective-see.org/tools.html)'s utilities close counterparts to nirsoft/sysinternals on Windows.